# Firebase rewrite based on subdomain

Tags: firebase-hosting

I've got a project hosted on firebase. I'd like to use a domain and subdomain as follows:

```
example.com: rewrite to index-landing.html
app.example.com: rewrite to index.html
```

Is that possible? I've tried the following under the hosting section of firebase.json:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "https://example.com",
    "destination": "/index-landing.html"
  },
  {
    "source": "https://app.example.com/**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @jloosli we're looking to do exactly this. Did you find anything?

Comment: @AlanHaverty not through firebase...I ended up using two projects and pointing the dns at the two different ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue.  I think rewrites only support directories not subdomains.  The simple solution is to just create two different Firebase projects.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, this is now possible. I found this really good article/video while trying to find a solution: https://fireship.io/lessons/deploy-multiple-sites-to-firebase-hosting/